# CSS height 100% of page height?

Tags: css, height, lightbox, fade

SO I'm trying to make an all CSS lightbox such as the one on this page
[CSS Lightbox](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/downloads/lightbox.html)

but when the page is scrollable do to the height of it, and the user scrolls down, the fade stops, is there a way to stop this from happening?? So the fade covers the whole page regardless if they scroll or not..

THanks,

Comment: I thought lightboxes disabled scroll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
.black_overlay {
display: none;
position: absolute;
```

to

```
.black_overlay {
display: none;
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually grab the height and width of the originating page's body and set the height/width of the fade to those dimensions using Javascript before I add it to the page. Are you looking for a CSS only option or would you be willing to use a bit of JS?